# What is the meaning of `SCSI3 (0,0,0)` in Partition disks during Ubuntu installation?

Tags: partitioning, scsi

I observed the following message during Ubuntu installation. What is the meaning of `SCSI3 (0,0,0)` in Partition disks during Ubuntu installation?

I assume `SCSI3` is the `Small Computer System Interface 3` based on information from https://www.techopedia.com/definition/17302/scsi-3

> Small Computer System Interface 3 (SCSI-3) is an ongoing
>   standardization effort for extending the features of SCSI-2.

What about `(0,0,0)`? Any idea what are these numbers for?

I've attached the screenshot for your reference.

[click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC4Aq.jpg)

Comment: I am not sure who wrote that Techopedia article, but maybe they should get back and edit it. "Ongoing", really? It was released in 1993, *twenty-five* years ago!

Answer (score 4):

It means:

- Controller 0
- Disk 0
- Partition 0

So it is the 1st disk controller, the 1st disk and the 1st partition on that disk.

---

```
ls -1d /sys/class/scsi_device/*/device/block/*
```

will list them all and also show the device name used for it.Example:

```
$ ls -1d /sys/class/scsi_device/*/device/block/*
/sys/class/scsi_device/2:0:0:0/device/block/sr0
/sys/class/scsi_device/4:0:0:0/device/block/sda
/sys/class/scsi_device/5:0:0:0/device/block/sdb
```

- [Linux device naming](ftp://ftp.iitb.ac.in/LDP/en/Partition-Mass-Storage-Definitions-Naming-HOWTO/ar01s05.html)

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind. I would like to read more about this. Do you have any link for reference?

Comment: Here you go. Most topics on device names will be explaining the /dev/sdNX The 0 0 0 from scsi is one level below that ;)